# Which filesystems reuse unchanged data blocks on write?

Tags: filesystems, io

Let's say I open and read an existing file of `N` blocks where `N > 1`.

Then I change data which resides within the boundaries of one - 1 - block.

On writing back the actual data, presumably one of the following could happen:

1. `N` blocks are overwritten
2. `1` block is overwritten
3. `x` blocks are overwritten, where `N > x > 1`

In widely used filesystems, are there examples of each of these, and which would they be?

Comment: Mostly variant 2. But it can vary from chance to chance, even on the same volume, file and altered data block.

Comment: 4. nothing is overwritten, 1 new block is allocated elsewhere and connected into the file instead of the original (e.g. btrfs)

Comment: Another possibility: the application writes to a new file. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75570/108618).

Comment: for a list of filesystems that do not overwrite stuff in place, see the warning in [man shred](https://linux.die.net/man/1/shred)

Comment: In many cases it is up to the programmer what happens.  In C you open a file in APPEND mode which jump to the end of the file, and unchanged blocks are not touched.  You can also open a file in binary mode, and use seek command to move to the exact location where the data is to be written.  However, at the hardware level a minimum of 1 sector has to be written so if you change 1 byte the other 511 might be re-written.  In addition, I believe SSD use 4k blocks in the background(below sector level) due for efficiency reasons.  The hardware controllers could have more optimizations.

Comment: However, the program could choose to not to just re-write the changed parts because that takes a lot more code.  Then dumping the whole file back to disk.  However, there could be further hardware optimizations inside the hard drive controller to minimize the unnecessary overwriting of data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're only touching *one* block, then either that one block will be overwritten, or no blocks will be overwritten.

The first situation is the case on a vast majority of filesystems in widespread usage today, as well as almost all historical filesystems.  Examples include NTFS, FAT, ext4, XFS, HFS, HFS+ and UFS.  Essentially, this is the simplest option and all the disadvantages are well known and pretty trivial to understand.

The second situation is what some newer filesystems do. Notably, BTRFS, ZFS, NILFS2, F2FS, and I believe ReFS, and APFS, do this (and the venerable Fossil archival filesystem from Plan 9 From Bell Labs, which I believe might have been the first to do this).  The way they work is a bit different.  Instead of directly overwriting the existing block, they write to a new, currently unused, one, and then update the file's metadata to point to that new copy instead, and free the old one.  This is a bit more complicated, but it ensures that the write either happens or does not, instead of leaving the possibility that it might only be partially completed.

Once you get past working with just that one block though, it gets complicated.  Depending on the system, you may or may not have new block allocations for the write.  You also might have new blocks allocated because of application behavior instead of the filesystem.  On many UNIX-like systems, it's pretty common for an application to write out the modified version of a file it's updating to a temporary file, then replace the old one by renaming the temporary file, because this ensures that the update either happens or doesn't.